# Asp .net Web Forms TreeView - PopulateNodesFromClient

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have control configured as below. control is populated from server without postback to server but after I make postback i can't get checked items. Is there any solution for this or maby there is other idea.

Main issue is to populate treeview without full page postback.

Thx for any help.

`<asp:TreeView ShowLines="True" runat="server" ID="trvCategories" ShowCheckBoxes="All" EnableClientScript="True" PopulateNodesFromClient="True" OnTreeNodePopulate="PopulateNode">
                        </asp:TreeView>`

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this in my VB.NET application; it may very well work in ASP.NET also.

```
Private Sub tvwDataCategory_AfterCheck(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewEventArgs) Handles tvwDataCategory.AfterCheck
Dim Node As System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode = eventArgs.Node
Dim n As Integer

If VB.Left(Node.Name, cTagLength) = cDataTypeTag Then
Node.ForeColor = DefaultForeColor

Dim nNodes As TreeNodeCollection = eventArgs.Node.Nodes

For Each nNode As TreeNode In nNodes
If nNodes.Count = 0 Then
If nNode.Checked Then
tvwDataCategory.Nodes.Item(n).Checked = True
Else
tvwDataCategory.Nodes.Item(n).Checked = False
End If
End If
Next
Else
Call FormatChecks()
End If
End Sub
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Thx for a respons You describe desktop TreeView control but I need solution for a web TreeView  :)